# Pointers for direct proof of extension of the Descartes Rule of Signs to complex polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, cv.complex-variables

The following describes an extension of the Descartes Rule of Signs to polynomials with complex coefficients.

First, I need to define the notion of a "sweep"... Given a complex polynomial p(z) := c<sub>0</sub> z<sup>m<sub>0</sub></sup> + c<sub>1</sub> z<sup>m<sub>1</sub></sup> + ... + c<sub>n</sub> z<sup>m<sub>n</sub></sup> with non-zero c<sub>i</sub> and strictly increasing m<sub>i</sub>, let {α<sub>i</sub>} be the coefficients' "non-decreasing argument sequence": α<sub>i</sub> = arg c<sub>i</sub> (mod 2π), and α<sub>0</sub> ≤ α<sub>1</sub> ≤ ... ≤ α<sub>n</sub>, with each α<sub>i+1</sub>-α<sub>i</sub> taken as small as possible; then α<sub>n</sub>-α<sub>0</sub> computes the "angular sweep" --which I'll denote **sweep(p)**-- of a needle with one end anchored at the origin of the Complex Plane that begins pointing at c<sub>0</sub> and then spins counter-clockwise to point at each c<sub>i</sub> in turn ("stalling in place" when consecutive coefficients have equal arguments).[*]

With this, we have:

**The Descartes Rule of Sweeps.** The number of positive real roots of p is at most $\lfloor \frac{1}{\pi} sweep(p)\rfloor$.

(The Descartes Rule of Signs represents a special case: each sign change in a polynomial's real coefficient sequence contributes π to the sweep, so that $\frac{1}{\pi}sweep(p)$ exactly counts those sign changes.)

Now, I can prove the Rule of Sweeps using the Descartes Rule of Signs itself, but that approach sheds no light on *why* the Rule of Signs works (which is what I'm really after). The result seems to be one clever contour away from falling directly out of the Cauchy Argument Principle --and it even seems curiously appropriate that the formula provides a kind of half-winding number from the coefficient sequence-- but apparently I'm not sufficiently clever. :(

Suggestions?

[*] Note: One can also compute a sweep of the coefficients taken in reverse order (or, equivalently, spinning the needle clockwise). Differently-directed sweeps are usually not equal, so we can optimize the bound in the Rule of Sweeps by taking "the" sweep as the minimum of the two directed sweeps.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use Roueche's theorem in the right way.  For example, you could try moving all the non-zero coefficients to the top degrees, since that wouldn't change the sweep.

Comment: Don: may I direct your attention to http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/322077.322084 ; sounds similar to what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I really like the part with taking the minimum of the two directions.  Very clever, especially given my first idea if I had come across this result would have just done counterclockwise and assumed the other direction was the opposite of it.

Answer (score 4):

This paper is related to generalizing Sturm's theorem rather than Descartes' rule of signs, but I think it is relevant:
http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0097

Answer (score 2):

The following paper by Jeff Lagarias and Tom Richardson "Multivariate Descartes rule of signs and Sturmfels' challenge problem" http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/intelligencer.pdf

looks like it has things relevant to your question.

Comment: It may take me a little time to wrap my mind around the concepts to determine relevancy. I'll note, however, that the provided solution to the "Sturmfels Challenge Problem" (counting non-zero real roots of a specific system of two polynomials in two variables) makes multiple appeals to the original Rule of Signs. It's not clear (to me), then, whether the algebraic machinery described (Newton polytopes and such) requires pre-supposing the original Rule of Signs to actually get anywhere. Such pre-supposing is specifically what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

[Obrechkoff](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3130n/f112.item) proved the following generalization:
[image: Obrechkoff generalization]

Tossing the text into Google-translate:

> Consider  $$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n = 0 $$ an equation with real coefficients, whose number of sign variations is $V$. Then the number of its roots, whose arguments lie between $-\alpha$ and $\alpha$ $(0 \le \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2})$, the limits $-\alpha$ and $\alpha$ being excluded, does not exceed $V + 2 \left[ \frac{n\alpha}{\pi}\right]$ (where $[x]$ denotes the largest integer contained in $x$) and if it is less, the difference is an even number.